# Pandas - when calculating a value using a column, set the value to 0 when the column meets a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame indexed by a date:

```
              id
2019-02-01  1234
2019-02-01  1234
2019-02-02  1234
2019-02-02  2345
2019-02-02  3456
2019-02-03  4567
2019-02-04  4567
2019-02-05     0
2019-02-06  1234
2019-02-07  2345
2019-02-08     0
```

There can be multiple ID's for the same day and the same ID's can occur on the same day. Note that the 0 values do not occur on days that have at least 1 valid ID.

I am attempting to calculate the average count per day per ID. I have the following that creates the average value:

```
df = df.groupby(df.index)[['id']].count() / df.groupby(df.index).agg({'id': 'nunique'})
```

Unfortunately this includes those ID's that have a value of 0, which results in the average count being set to 1 i.e 1 / 1. It needs to 0.

What I am hoping to achieve is that those days that have a 0 ID are by default set to 0, otherwise calculate the average.

I can't update the dataframe after the calculation as there can be valid average values of 1.

I am hoping there is an easy way to do this. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace 0 with `NaN` first, so that `0` values aren't counted:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].replace(0,np.nan)
df = df.groupby(df.index)['id'].count().to_frame()
df
Out[1]: 
            id
2019-02-01   2
2019-02-02   3
2019-02-03   1
2019-02-04   1
2019-02-05   0
2019-02-06   1
2019-02-07   1
2019-02-08   0
```

If you want to ONLY do this on days where there is only one value, then you can do the same thing but only for days where the count is 1 with `mask` and checking if index `value_counts() == 1`:

```
df['id'] = df['id'].mask(df.index.value_counts() == 1, df['id'].replace(0,np.nan))
df = df.groupby(df.index)['id'].count().to_frame()
df
Out[2]: 
            id
2019-02-01   2
2019-02-02   3
2019-02-03   1
2019-02-04   1
2019-02-05   0
2019-02-06   1
2019-02-07   1
2019-02-08   0
```